# Как присвоить диагоналям на которых лежит выбранный пользователем элемент любое значение?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_array(int** array, int N, int M) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << right << array[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5, M = 5;

    int** array;

    array = new int* [N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new int[M];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Before" << endl;
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    while (cin >> x >> y)
{

    print_array(array, N, M);//Вывод матрицы ДО изменений

    //Операции изменений над матрицей

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {

                array[i][y] = 0;
                array[x][j] = 0;
            
        }
    }



    cout << "After" << endl; //Вывод матрицы после изменений

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << right << array[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    system("pause");

}

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        delete[] array[i];
    }

    delete[] array;

}
```

Comment: Уточнение: у Вас есть матрица, пользователь выбирает на ней элемент (вводит индексы), после чего Вам, образно говоря, нужно "нарисовать крест" на этой матрице из двух диагоналей, которые перекрещивались бы на том элементе, который выбрал пользователь, так?

Comment: Да, нужен крест на элементе из диагоналей

Comment: Понял, сейчас попробую накидать ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код имеет необходимый функционал взамен того, что был изначально.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_array(int** array, int N, int M)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << right << array[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5, M = 5;

    int** array;

    array = new int*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new int[M];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Before" << endl;
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    while (cin >> x >> y)
    {

        print_array(array, N, M);//Вывод матрицы ДО изменений

                                 //Операции изменений над матрицей

        /*for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {

                array[i][y] = 0;
                array[x][j] = 0;

            }
        }*/
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Здесь начинается добавленный код
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Рисуем "луч" вправо вниз
        for (int i = x, j = y; (i < N) && (j < M); i++, j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
        // Рисуем "луч" влево вниз
        for (int i = x, j = y; (i < N) && (j >= 0); i++, j--)
        {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
        // Рисуем "луч" влево вверх
        for (int i = x, j = y; (i >= 0) && (j >= 0); i--, j--)
        {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
        // Рисуем "луч" вправо вверх
        for (int i = x, j = y; (i >= 0) && (j < M); i--, j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Здесь заканчивается добавленный код
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        cout << "After" << endl; //Вывод матрицы после изменений

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                cout << setw(5) << right << array[i][j];
            }

            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;

        system("pause");

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        delete[] array[i];
    }

    delete[] array;

}
```

Решение "в лоб" и использует 4 цикла для отрисовки каждого из "лучей креста". Возможно, найдутся более элегантные варианты, но этот тоже рабочий и имеет место быть.

Алгоритм простой, но вкратце поясню: чтобы нарисовать один "луч", нужно на каждой итерации цикла сразу увеличивать оба счётчика, чтобы "двигаться по диагонали". Для этого в теле `for` проинициализированы, проверяются и изменяются сразу `i` и `j`. Когда один из счётчиков доходит до границ матрицы, прорисовка очередного "луча" заканчивается.

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы на каждую итерацию цикла вызывалась новая матрица? иначе они накладываются друг на друга

Comment: @RxNsx, не понял Вас, какой именно цикл и кто куда накладывается?

Comment: матрица одна на другую накладывается, т.е можно занулить всю. а цикл While где пользователь вводит интересующий его для отрисовки элемент

Comment: @RxNsx теперь понял. Для этого Вам нужно строку `array = new int*[N];` и следующие за ней два цикла заполнения матрицы пустыми значениями внести в цикл `while`

Comment: @RxNsx Ну и очистка памяти с помощью `delete` тогда, конечно же, тоже должна быть внутри `while`.

Comment: такой глупый вопрос получился, спасибо, мог бы и сам додуматься

Comment: @RxNsx, всегда рад помочь :)